# Can not edit/delete file in the directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

While I was doing the following, I can not update the file(noimg100.gif) in Visual Studio 2005.

Here is the code,

```
String fileNotFoundPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/common/images/noimg100.gif");
context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
Image notFoundImage = Image.FromFile(fileNotFoundPath);
notFoundImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Am I doing anything wrong or do I need to dispose the image at the end?

Edit:
I have found the following link, where it says about not to use Image.FromFile the way I have used:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309482

Comment: Update?! You're writing the image to response for download not updating server side one, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open an image from a file, the file is kept open as long as the image exists. As you don't dispose the `Image` object, it will continue to exist until the garbage collector finalises it and disposes it.

Dispose the `Image` object at the end of the code, and it will be possible to write to the file again.

You can use a `using` block to dispose the object, then you are sure that it will always be disposed, even if an error occurs in the code:

```
String fileNotFoundPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/common/images/noimg100.gif");
context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
using (Image notFoundImage = Image.FromFile(fileNotFoundPath)) {
  notFoundImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
}
```

Also, as you don't change the image in any way, it's a waste to uncompress it and then recompress it. Just open the file and write it to the stream:

```
String fileNotFoundPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/common/images/noimg100.gif");
context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
using (FileStream notFoundImage = File.OpenRead(fileNotFoundPath)) {
  notFoundImage.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```